# Can a Jupyter / IPython notebook take arguments in the URL?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to write an Jupyter notebook such that parameters can be passed in via the URL of the notebook?

Example, for a URL such as this:

```
http://jupyter.example.com/user/me/notebooks/notebook1.ipynb?Variable1=Value1&Variable2=Value2
```

how could access `Variable1` and `Variable2` inside the Jupyter cell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to find out the URL using JavaScript and pass it to the IPython kernel:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''
    <script type="text/javascript">
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("URL = '" + window.location + "'")
    </script>''')
```

or:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("URL = '" + window.location + "'");
```

Then in the next cell:

```
print(URL)
```

After this you can use the tools in the standard library (or plain string operations) to pull out the query parameters.

Comment: I marked this question as answered before I tried it. I'm struggling to make it work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37172978/1698426 .

Comment: I had working with an additional double quote: 
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("URL = '" + window.location + "'");

Comment: There's a package that does the handling of the pulling out for you as long as you add a cell with `# Parameters:` as the content. See [Jupyter Notebook Params](https://github.com/manics/jupyter-notebookparams), which includes a `launch binder` badge for letting you run a demo in a temporary session backed via the MyBinder service.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to take the values with javascript and push them to the ipython kernel like in the John Schmitt's link.

Cell [1]:

```
%%javascript
function getQueryStringValue (key)
{  
    return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
}
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("Var1='".concat(getQueryStringValue("Variable1")).concat("'"));
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("Var2='".concat(getQueryStringValue("Variable2")).concat("'"));
```

And in another cell you can retrieve the python variables named Var1 and Var2:

```
>>>print Var1
Value1
```

And:

```
>>>print Var2
Value2
```