# Uncaught ReferenceError: IPython is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I try to pass a javascript variable to python in a jupyter notebook, as described in [How to pass variables from javascript to python in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37172978/1933185)

Somehow the `IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("foo=97")` seems not to work, but IPython itself works.

Here my code from the jupyter notebook

```
# [1]
from IPython.display import HTML

# [2]
HTML('''<script>console.log('foo=101')</script>''')

# [3]
HTML('''
  <script type="text/javascript">
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("foo=97")
  </script>
 ''')
```

Executing cell [2] after cell [1] shows in the console `foo=101`. Executing cell [3] shows this error in the console

```
VM1448:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: IPython is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:5
    at t.attachWidget (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:1594384)
    at t.insertWidget (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:1593735)
    at j._insertOutput (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:925178)
    at j.onModelChanged (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:922355)
    at m (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:1560386)
    at Object.l [as emit] (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:1560046)
    at e.emit (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:1558291)
    at c._onListChanged (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:918778)
    at m (jlab_core.e37d4bbc8c984154bc26.js?v=e37d4bbc8c984154bc26:2:1560386)
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

My jupyter setup:

```
IPython          : 8.6.0
ipykernel        : 6.17.1
ipywidgets       : 8.1.1
jupyter_client   : 7.4.7
jupyter_core     : 5.0.0
jupyter_server   : 1.23.2
jupyterlab       : 3.5.0
nbclient         : 0.7.0
nbconvert        : 7.2.5
nbformat         : 5.7.0
notebook         : 6.5.2
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.5.0
```

Comment: Your first link references a post from **2016**. Jupyter has evolved quite a bit since then and you aren't telling us what version of anything you are using? More modern tech in Jupyter won't work with those older more 'hacking'-style approaches. See my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75866820/8508004), and for a very high-level answer, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/executing-java-script-code-in-jupyterlab-gives-error/14894/2?u=fomightez) where original question was trying to use `kernel.execute()` like you. What are you trying to do that you thought you could ...

Comment: <continued> use that approach to pass between Python and Javascript?  I ask because there may be a better way to achieve the actual goal.

Comment: @Wayne I want to drag and drop csv files to my jupyter notebook and work with this csv files in jupyter. My missing part is, to get the csv-string which I have in javascript, available in python.

Comment: Sounds like a job for https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/8.1.2/examples/Widget%20List.html#file-upload

Comment: Could not find drag and drop, but the [file upload](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/8.1.2/examples/Widget%20List.html#file-upload) seems interessting. Thanks

Comment: Drag-and-drop does work with the file upload tool of ipywidgets. Last time I looked into it, it was a bit temperamental for dragging multiple files at once but one at a time worked. Another way to go is to use JupyterLab that features a nice file navigation pane that you can drag and drop files from your local computer into. You can usually use the markdown in the notebook to guide users through the steps for doing that. You can make it have less code in the notebook itself by putting most of the code in an associated script.