# Jupyter notebook http://localhost:8889/notebooks/test.ipynb?variable1+variable2 opened in Chrome: how to get url?

Tags: python, google-chrome, url, jupyter-notebook

I seems that whatever comes the .ipynb extension, the notebook will open. How can I get the url to use the characters behind the extension as variables for instance?

I am using Chrome both in Windows and OSX.

I am asked to edit my question but the answer of Luis shows he got it!

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is.  Are you asking how to pass in variables when calling a .ipynb file from a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or with following syntax to do it in one cell:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''
    <script type="text/javascript>
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("URL = ' + window.location + "'")
    </script>''')
print(URL)
```

I actually oversaw following question [Can a Jupyter / IPython notebook take arguments in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818127/can-a-jupyter-ipython-notebook-take-arguments-in-the-url) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need get parameters from url in python jupyter notebook, use the magic function:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("URL = '" + window.location + "'")
```

and in the other cell:

```
print(URL)
```

---