# Fill form fields in Colab notebook from URL query parameters

Tags: google-colaboratory

How can I dynamically populate a form field in my Colab notebook from a URL query parameter so I can construct preconfigured links to it from another system? I tried adapting [Can a Jupyter / IPython notebook take arguments in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818127/can-a-jupyter-ipython-notebook-take-arguments-in-the-url) but the JS in colab runs in a sandboxed iframe with a referrer policy which removed the path and query from document.referrer.

I would also like to make it as easy as possible for someone following such a link to run the notebook on the data supplied in the form fields. Is it possible to connect and run all automatically on opening a notebook? Is there a way to display a 'Run all' button so the user does not have to hunt for it in the menu?