# IPython.notebook.kernel.execute in the same cell

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, voila

I have a follow up question to
[Can a Jupyter / IPython notebook take arguments in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818127/can-a-jupyter-ipython-notebook-take-arguments-in-the-url)

There is an assumption here that the HTML object should be the last one in the cell and the print URL is in the next one. Is it possible to get the URL directly without these assumptions?
I need it in an app that runs through a package voila. A snippet of code(like below from the other query on stackoverflow) in a single cell would be ideal.

```
*from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''
    <script type="text/javascript">
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("URL = '" + window.location + "'")
    </script>''')
print(URL)*
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert a div and print the url into this div:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''
    <div id="url_output"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("url_output").innerHTML = window.location
    </script>
''')
```

Comment: by the way, you don't need to place the HTML as the last object. You can simply display(HTML('bla bla')) and add other objects, and it will work. But in your example, HTML code and print(URL) code runs in the same execution and the URL is not yet populated because of the script is not yet executed in the output cell.